# Format USB stick using LVM?

Tags: 12.04, usb, backup, lvm

Is it possible to format a USB stick using LVM?  I am interested in LVM because apparently it allows you to create instantaneous snapshots for backup purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

assume your usb is mounted as sdb1 :

Install lvm :

```
sudo apt-get install lvm2
```

Create physical volume :

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/sdb1
```

Check if your physical volume is created :

```
sudo pvscan
```

Create volume group :

```
sudo vgcreate "Nameyouwant" /dev/sdb1
```

Check volume groups :

```
sudo vgscan
```

Create logical volume (suppose we will use ext3):

```
sudo lvcreate -l 100%FREE -next3 "Nameofvolumegroup"
```

Create ext3 partition :

```
sudo mkfs.ext3 /dev/nameyouchoose/ext3
```

Mount your logical volume :

sudo mount /dev/seagate/ext3 /path you want

You can now store your backups .